# Inequality $8(a^4+b^4) \ge (a+b)^4$

Tags: inequality

This inequality supposed to proven without using any known theorem (AM-GM inequality), just to be proved on the fact that square of any real number is greater than or equal to $0$.

After exapansion I got 
$7a^4+7b^4-4a^3b-6a^2b^2-4ab^3 \ge 0$

But I am struck here.any hints

Comment: Isn't it $-6a^2b^2$?

Comment: Also, what _exactly_ does "without using any known theorem" mean? Or do you just mean specifically without AM-GM?

Comment: Yes,I fixed it. No I mean all other too like Cauchy ,am gm..etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have:

$$8(a^4+b^4)-(a+b)^4=(a-b)^2(7a^2+10ab+7b^2)\geq 0$$

**How to deduce it without expanding** Using AM-GM we have:

$$8ab(a^2+b^2) \leq (a^2+b^2+2ab)^2=(a+b)^4$$

from which is easy to see the identity (as in $(x+y)^2-4xy=(x-y)^2$):

$$(a+b)^4-8ab(a^2+b^2)=(a^2+b^2-2ab)^2=(a-b)^4$$

Also,

$$a^4+b^4-ab(a^2+b^2)=(a^2+b^2)^2-2a^2b^2-ab(a^2+b^2)=(a-b)^2(a^2+ab+b^2)$$

Therefore:

$$
\begin{aligned}
8(a^4+b^4)-(a+b)^4 &= 8[a^4+b^4-ab(a^2+b^2)]-[(a+b)^4-8ab(a^2+b^2)]\\
&=8(a-b)^2(a^2+ab+b^2)-(a-b)^4\\
&=(a-b)^2(7a^2+10ab+7b^2)
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: @Arricus After seeing your factorization i tried to do on my own but it didn't worked.Can you explain your motive in factorization above??I can't get intuition how you came up with it??

Comment: @MathematicalCuriosity, The motivation is like this: since it's hard (or long-winded) to find a relation between $a^4+b^4$ and $(a+b)^4$, I tried to come up with a term to add and subtract, that's easy to factorize with both expressions. And that's $8ab(a^2+b^2)$ because $(a^4+b^4)=(a^2+b^2)^2-2a^2b^2$ and $(a+b)^4=(a^2+b^2+2ab)^2$. That was my reasoning. The rest is just experience and handiness with identities and inequalities (I used the inequality $8ab(a^2+b^2)\leq (a+b)^4$ many times before).

Answer (score 3):

Using the identity $(x+y)^2 + (x-y)^2 = 2(x^2+y^2)$, we have

$$\begin{align}
8(a^4+b^4) &= 4(a^2+b^2)^2 + 4(a^2-b^2)^2\\
&= ((a+b)^2 + (a-b)^2)^2 + 4(a^2-b^2)^2\\
&= (a+b)^4 + (a-b)^4 + 6(a^2-b^2)^2\\
&\ge (a+b)^4 + 0 + 0\\
&= (a+b)^4
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1**

Using convexity of $x\mapsto x^4$,
$$\left(a+b\right)^4=2^4\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^4\leq 2^3(a^4+b^4).$$

**Method 2**

Using Holder inequality,
$$|a+b|\leq |a|+|b|\leq (1+1)^{\frac{3}{4}}(a^4+b^4)^\frac{1}{4}$$
and thus $$(a+b)^4\leq 2^3(a^4+b^4).$$

Comment: You can also use Muirhead but I think OP likes none of these since he wants the $$(a-b)^2(7a^2+10ab+7b^2)$$ decomposition

Comment: Just because I am not advanced enough to understand it

Comment: @MathematicalCuriosity I think the following generalization is good to keep in mind: For any $r\geq1$ and $a,b\geq 0$, we have $$a^r+b^r\le(a+b)^r\le 2^{r-1} (a^r+b^r)$$ This follows from convexity of $x\mapsto x^r$ and I encourage you to prove it

Comment: @Maximillian janisch these are my thoughts: First party of inequality is trivial.For second part let us take $a\ge b$ then $a^r\ge a^jb^{r-j}$ this results in $(a+b)^r\ge 2^{r-1}a^r+b^r+b^{r-1}a$ but not sure how to move forward

Comment: @MathematicalCuriosity Let me give you this hint: Let $f(x)=x^r$. Then $f$ is convex. So by Jensen $$f\left(\frac{a+b}2\right)\le \frac{f(a)+f(b)}2$$

Answer (score 0):

You can factor further

$$7a^4-4a^3b-6a^2b^2-4ab^3+7=(a-b)^2(7a^2+10ab+7b^2)$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f(x)=8(1+x^4)-(1+x)^4 \implies f'(x)=32 x^3-4(1+x)^3, f''(x)=96x^2-12(1+x)^2.$$
$$ f'(x)=0 \implies x=1, f''(1)=48>0 \implies f_{min}=f(1)=0.$
So finally, we have $$f(x)\ge f(1) \implies 8(1+x^4) \ge (1+x)^4$$
Let $x=b/a$, we get $$8(a^4+b^4) \ge (a+b)^4.$$

Answer (score 0):

We have
\begin{align*}
8(a^4+b^4)-(a+b)^4&=7a^4+7b^4-4a^3b-6a^2b^2-4ab^3\\
&=7a^5-14a^2b^2+7b^2-4a^3b+8a^2b^2-4ab^3\\
&=7(a^2-b^2)^2-4ab(a-b)^2\\
&=(a-b)^2[7(a+b)^2-4ab]\\
&=(a-b)^2(7a^2+10ab+7b^2)\\
&=(a-b)^2[2(a^2+b^2)+5(a+b)^2]\\
\end{align*}
Both factors in the RHS are $\ge 0$ since they are squares or sum of squares of real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Another way.

By C-S twice we obtain:
$$8(x^4+y^4)=4(1+1)(a^4+b^4)\geq4(a^2+b^2)^2=((1+1)(a^2+b^2))^2\geq(a+b)^4.$$